# После пересоздания аккаунта в чате и на странице входящих сообщений отображается мой старый аккаунт

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано

Ситуация такая.

- Я удалил аккаунт (он действительно удалился, о чём пришло письмо на
  почту).
- Я зарегистрировал новый аккаунт на тот же почтовый адрес и с тем же
  никнеймом.
- Однако если я перехожу на страницу входящих сообщений, то
  отображаются не только новые, полученные с нового аккаунта, но и
  старые, которые пришли на старый аккаунт. При этом отображается моя
  старая аватарка и старый текст в "О себе".
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Точно так же отображается моя старая аватарка в чатах, куда переносят
  *новые* обсуждения, которые я вёл с *нового* аккаунта. При клике на аватарку в обсуждениях открывается опять-таки страница с моим старым
  аккаунтом: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
  Причём, прошу заметить, при клике на ник открывается страница 404, но при этом система считает, что я пишу сообщения всё ещё со старого аккаунта (последнее сообщение 17 минут назад).

**Получается, что мой прошлый аккаунт как-то не до конца удалился... или система просто запуталась. В общем, хотелось бы вопрос разрулить.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я верно понял ситуацию, ваша учетная запись в чате не была удалена, потому что у вас осталась учетная запись на одном из сайтов Stack Exchange. Про удаление очень подробно написано на [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999/274323). Если кратко:

- Учетная запись не всегда удаляется полностью в случае блокировки на публикацию вопросов или ответов. Это позволяет системе эффективно бороться со спамом, а также получением бонуса за ассоциацию несколько раз.
- Учетные записи на каждом сайте сети Stack Exchange необходимо удалять отдельно. Удаление учетной записи на одном сайте, не приведет к ее удалению на всех сайтах.
- Удаление учетной записи в чате произойдет во время удаления всех учетных записей в сети Stack Exchange.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Нет, из всех сайтов сети я был зарегистрирован только на сайте "Русский язык". По крайней мере, я не помню, чтобы у меня в правом меню, где справка-чат-выйти, были какие-то ещё сайты, кроме Русского языка и Русского языка meta.

Comment: @Nektoid [На странице вашего сетевого профиля](https://stackexchange.com/users/23726164/nektoid?tab=accounts) видно, что на текущий момент у вас есть учетные записи на двух сайтах: Russian language и Русский язык.

Comment: На сайте Russian language я зарегистрировался уже *после* того, как удалил аккаунт и создал новый. В профиле видно, что я там обитаю всего семь дней, и я не помню, чтобы регистрировался там с прошлого аккаунта. https://i.imgur.com/HudsTVy.png

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, через сколько после удаления старой учетной записи вы создали новую?

Comment: Впрочем, я сейчас нажал Update profile info — и профиль сменился на мой нынешний. И в списке входящих сообщений пропали те, которые приходили ещё на прошлый профиль. Получается, что сетевой профиль не был удалён, когда я удалился с сайта Русский язык?

Comment: Я думаю, около суток или меньше.

Comment: @Nektoid Спасибо! Многие вещи на сайте происходят асинхронно. То есть раз в какой–то промежуток времени запускается алгоритм, который удаляет участников, чистит кэш и т.д. Вполне возможно, что вы удалили / восстановили учетную запись до работы алгоритма удаления учетной записи чата. Я вижу, что с удаления вашей учетной записи системой до повторного входа прошло чуть больше 4 часов.

Comment: Да, если вам необходимо дисассоциировать сообщения в чате или удалить учетную запись чата, пожалуйста, дайте знать.

Comment: Да нет, теперь, после обновления профиля, всё выглядит корректно. Спасибо и простите за беспокойство :)